# How to replace SVG images OR How to replace div content?

Tags: google-chrome, svg, greasemonkey, userscripts

I want to create a userscript that replaces the default dog tag image (PNG) on http://battlelog.battlefield.com/ with my own image.
I tried several ways to do that but none of these worked.

First I tried following :

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName ("img");
var x=0;
while(x<images.length)
{
if(images[x].src == "http://battlelog-cdn.battlefield.com/public/profile/bf3/stats/dogtags/la/defaulttag_right.png?v=3173239")
{
images[x].src = "http://site.com/test.png";
}
x=x+1;
}
```

after this didnt work i wanted to include an external js but this fails too.
The external script :

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
           $(document).ready(function(){
               $('dogtag2-render').load('http://root.x10.bz/cdn.html');
           });
        </script>
```

Here is the snippet of the sourcecode where the img tag is located :

```
<div id="dogtag2-render">

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="320" height="200">

<desc>Created with Raphaël</desc>

<defs></defs>

<image x="10" y="0" width="256" height="148" preserveAspectRatio="none" href="http://battlelog-cdn.battlefield.com/public/profile/bf3/stats/dogtags/la/defaulttag_right.png?v=3173239"></image>

</svg>

</div>
```

Could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: are you sure your script is running at all ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a content script instead of a greasemonkey script.
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html
It'll run on your page if you specify this in the manifest.json:

```
{
"name": "My Extension",
...
"content_scripts": [
{
  "matches": ["http://battlelog.battlefield.com/"],
  "js": ["jquery.js", "myscript.js"]
}
],
...
}
```

Then to find your image and replace it with something new, I'd use some jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('img[src="the_old_images_src.jpg"]').attr('src','the_new_images_src.jpg');
});
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are willing to nuke that whole div, this code should work for you, no jQuery needed:

```js
var dogtagDiv       = document.querySelector ("#dogtag2-render");
dogtagDiv.innerHTML = '<img src="http://site.com/test.png" />';
```

---

---

Note that first attempt failed because `<img>` tags are not the same as SVG `<image>` tags, and I'm not sure you can manipulate SVG documents that way.

The second attempt failed because (1) `$('dogtag2-render')` should be `$('#dogtag2‑render')` and (2) `load()` will not work cross-domain.